# Part of the plot is missing, while using Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am having a code and using it to plot the curve(using `Manipulate`).
Here is the code

```
Nd = 8;
H1[t1_] := {{0, t1}, {t1, 0}};
H2[t2_] := {{0, 0}, {t2, 0}};
DistributeDefinitions[H1, H2];
H[t1_, t2_] := 
  ArrayFlatten@
   ParallelTable[
    H1[t1] KroneckerDelta[m, p1] + H2[t2] KroneckerDelta[m + 1, p1] + 
     Transpose[H2[t2]] KroneckerDelta[m - 1, p1], {m, 1, Nd}, {p1, 
     1, Nd}];
mp[t1_, t2_] := Module[{V1}, V1 = Eigenvalues[H[t1, t2]];
  V = V1*V1;
  Plot[V1, {t1, 0, 20}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]]
Manipulate[mp[t1, t2], {t2, 0, 20}]
```

The problem I am facing is there is some part of the plot missing when I set `t2 = 20`. It should be all the way to $20$ (along $x$- aixs).
 Is there some reason behind that?
[image]

This seems to start from `t2 = 13` onwards, why? I don't know.

*NOTEs AND GOOD OBSERVATIONs*:
i) Please move slider gently, don't jump directly to `t2=20`.
ii) By directly typing the value in the little box(shown above in the image). Then I get the full curve(once I displace it from that position using the cursor), then again I get the same, above truncated plot. That also I don't understand.

Comment: `t1` seems to be an input parameter and a variable in the plot.  If you look at your `Manipulate` statement (in *Mathematica*), you'll see `t1` in blue which means it's undefined.

Comment: Can't consistently reproduce your problem, but from a code point of view I don't like how `mp` takes `t1` as a function argument and as the localized plotting variable.  I would rewrite the code like [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/LD2aLvKD)

Comment: @JasonB. It has solved my problem, though I couldn't understand the reason for my case. May not be important now, I am ready to give the details that what problems I facing is authentic, however, reasons I don't know. Please try to make that(good one) as an answer, thanks by the way.

Comment: @JasonB. I tried to prove my words, see the edited question.